# How return value from anonymous method to label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want look, how work anonymous method and show result in label (Windows Forms):

```
label1.Text = () => { return "Some text"; };
```

But it's not work. How it's fix?

Comment: `Text` is a `string`, not a `Func<string>`.

Comment: What's the use for this? Why the one line requirement?

Comment: I need very small code in one project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
label1.Text = new Func<string>(() => { return "Some text"; })();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Func<string> func = () =>
{
    return "Some text";
};

label1.Text= func();
```

In one line

```
label1.Text= new Func<string>(() => "Some text")();
```

Comment: @titans Updated for one line